# Can I install a whole-house water filter in my garage?

Tags: garage

I live in Winchester TN, in a one level home. The water line comes into the garage from under the house. I want to put it in the garage (in case of a leak. My husband states it may freeze. I do not believe it gets cold enough to freeze. Neither do a lot of the neighbors. What do you suggest?

Comment: Are you asking us whether it will freeze, or what?

Comment: And, what do you mean when you say "put it in the garage"? Is this a faucet, or a water line that you're moving?

Answer (score 2):

If the existing water line is exposed in your garage and has never frozen, it stands to reason that neither would any other water fixture in the same vicinity.